# Get last pk without commit?

Tags: python, mysql

Is there a way to get the last PK inserted without doing a `COMMIT`? Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
self.cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO main_catalog VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (item[0], item[1], item[2], False, 'GOOGLE'))
self.conn.commit()
self.cursor2.execute('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()')
last_pk = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

How would I do that without the `self.conn.commit()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `cursor.lastrowid`, even within a transaction (i.e. without having called or before calling `conn.commit`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html